# How to automatically build new customized images based on changes in an existing project?

Tags: docker, github, github-actions

In many cases of existing docker images, when one wants to add some extra features (some plugins, specific configuration), a general rule is "build your own image" (with often precise information about what to add to the `Dockerfile` etc.)

While this is simple as a one-shot solution, it will not work great in an environment where I have all my docker images up to date (thanks to [watchtower](https://github.com/containrrr/watchtower)).

What is the correct way, in GitHub, to translate *"once there is a change in https://github.com/AUTHOR/REPO, automatically build a new image with these modifications"* (the modifications would probably be described in the CI/CD script).

EDIT: the case I have in mind is when the repo is not mine (I would normally just get the image from DOcker Hub, but since I want to add features, I need to rebuild that repo belonging to someone else when it changes)

I do not use GitHib but rather GitLab with its CI/CD model configured via its [`.gitlab-ci.yml`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/) but the majority of the repos I would like to tweak are on GitHub.

Comment: You can automatically build your images where there is a push with Docker Hub , you must first connect your repo : https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/link-source/. Then, documentation about automated build is here : https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/. Could this be a solution for you ?

Comment: @norbjd: thanks - with your comment I realized that I was not clear that the repo is not mine. I edited the question to highlight this.

Comment: Last time I checked it wasn't possible to receive notifications on events for repositories that aren't your own.